# Why would an access to the 32-bit view of HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive fall back to 64-bit view?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, registry, wow64

My 32-bit application is running on 64-bit Windows 7. I am trying to access the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. I can see in regedit that I have several subkeys below the `Uninstall` key in the default 64-bit registry view (Dropbox creates a key in that location, as well as Google Chrome). However, there is really no `Uninstall` key in the 32-bit registry view. Actually, in regedit there is only a single `Active Setup` key below `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft`. There is not even a `Windows` subkey below `Microsoft`.

However, when my 32-bit application tries to access the 32-bit registry view of `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, I get the keys from the 64-bit view. **Why is that?**

Even the flag [KEY_WOW64_32KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) won't help here. Our code needs to know whether the results are from the 32-bit view or the 64-bit view.

Our code also accesses both the 32-bit and 64-bit views of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and I do not see this issue there. The difference is that the 32-bit view of HKLM has an `Uninstall` key and the 32-bit view of HKCU does not.

I know the registry redirection of WoW64, but this seems different. I could not really find any useful information on MSDN. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What good would maintaining two separate lists of installed programs be? There's only one Control Panel, only one Uninstall list. And nothing is inherently bitness-specific in that list - not like it lists DLLs to load into a process. I guess there's an exception to the general redirection mechanism for that key.

Comment: If your program doesn't have a manifest that contains requestedExecutionLevel then you could be looking at a nasty mix of registry virtualization and registry redirection.

Comment: Very valid points. However what if one application has both 32 bit and 64 bit installation and they have both application name and version? We would like to be able to differentiate these type of situation. I just tried with Java and its 64 bit application name has the 64 bit appended at end. I guess application would have to make sure names are different at this case, otherwise control panel won't be able to handle it.

Comment: @Hans, thanks. we already have that, here is part of our manifest file: <security><requestedPrivileges><requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel></requestedPrivileges></security>

Comment: Bringing up the 32-bit version of regedit, it appears that the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software key is not redirected at all - there is no separate 32-bit view.  There is a Wow6432Node key, but it looks to me like that was created by mistake.  I don't think this is anything to do with the Uninstall key in particular.  You may have to take another approach.

Comment: @Harry, thanks. I am able to bring up the 32 bit regedit by following this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097) with %systemroot%\syswow64\regedit (or add -m option). Yes, I saw the same thing. Definitely some new learning here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented, but only indirectly. This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists `HKLM\Software` as redirected and `HKCU\Software` as shared.

**Note:** in this context *redirected* means that there are two registry views, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit (in other words: the `Wow6432Node` subkey exists and is used), whereas *shared* means that there is only one view for 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

And yes, it is interesting that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node` exists. As the OP mentioned there is only a subkey `Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components` below that - which is probably there because the autors of the Active Setup code at Microsoft incorrectly used the `Wow6432Node` as subkey path in their registry API calls instead of specifying the desired view via the `samDesired` parameter of `RegOpenKeyEx`.

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this question based on the comment I got so far and there is no official confirmation on this. So at this point basically there is really no 32 bit registry for KKEY_CURRENT_USER at 64 bit machine.